# How can I use VBA in a VB.net application?

Tags: vb.net, vba

I wonder if it is possible to integrate VBA in my VB.NET application. If so, do you know of any general tutorial that explains how to do this?

Comment: Some time ago, I've created an integration of VBScript (not VBA though) into a C# application. You can [take a look at an example](http://blog.magerquark.de/using-active-scripting-from-within-c-without-leaking-memory/).

Answer (score 1):

Add the `Microsoft Excel Object Library 12.0` (12.0 for Excel 2007, 14.0 for Excel 2010) from the COM tab of the `Add Reference` dialog.

The syntax is quite similar, if you are familiar with VBA, you'll pick it up quickly.

```
Dim wkbk As Workbook
Dim wkst As Worksheet

Set wkbk = Workbooks.Add
Set wkst = wkbk.Worksheets(1)
wkst.Range("A3").Select
ActiveCell.Value = "Put text here"
```

in VBA, becomes

```
Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Dim oExcel As Object
Dim Book As Excel.Workbook
Dim Sheet As Excel.Worksheet

oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Book = oExcel.Workbooks.Add()
Sheet = Book.Worksheets(1)
Sheet.Range("A3").Select()
oExcel.ActiveCell.Value = "Put text here"
```

with the Interop.

Any of the worksheet functions would be available off of the `WorksheetFunction` property of the `oExcel` object.

Answer (score 0):

[Older tutorial using COM](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/303871).

[This one is more aligned with using the Interop Namespace](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=441071).